# Determining the chart id (Highcharts)

Tags: highcharts

I have three highcharts containers on the same page and want to create a function which is available to all charts, so I have defined the function in setOptions. The function is working well but I don't know which graph has triggered the event.

How do I know which chart triggered the event?

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            allowPointSelect: true,
            point: {
                events: {
                    select: function () {
                        alert($(this).attr('id')); // I need this to be the chart id
                    }
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

- use `this.series.chart.options.chart.renderTo` to get string you have passed when creating chart
- use `this.series.chart.renderTo.id` to get ID's string, (will be the same as above).

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly, first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.series.chart` to get the chart object that was clicked.  I'm not sure how you're assigning an "ID" to your chart, but presumably having a handle to the chart itself will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. Here is what I am trying to do: I have three charts. Each point on the chart has a client ID and the ID's are common to all three charts. When the user clicks a data point on chart1 I want to mark the corresponding points on charts 2 and 3. I dont want to remark chart1 or I will get caught in an infinite loop.

Comment: It would help if you make a jsFiddle for us to play with.